# NuGet command line checkout packages.config

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, nuget, nuget-package

My project is currently referencing some pre-release packages that represent nightly builds. I would like to ensure that I am always building against the latest release. I added a pre-build event to my project:

```
.nuget\nuget.exe update -safe -noninteractive -prerelease -source "My-Package-Repo/nuget" $(SolutionPath)
```

This generates the following output during build:

```
Scanning for projects...
Found 1 projects with a packages.config file. (MyProject)
Looking for installed packages in '..\..\packages'.
Updating 'MyProject'...
EXEC : warning : Access to the path 'C:\workspace\mainline\MyProject\packages.config' is denied.
```

The problem is that the packages.config file is still locked by source control and therefore NuGet cannot update the package version.  Interestingly, if I run `update-package` from the Package Manager Console, it automatically checks out the packages.config file and updates all packages for the solution.

Is there a way to have NuGet automatically check out the packages.config file when using the command line interface? Alternatively, is it possible to run the update-package command within the PM console as a pre-build event (since it already has the behavior I need)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been dealing with this recently myself. Unfortunately, nuget.exe update won't check out the files by itself and the package manager console only runs within Visual Studio (it apparently hooks into the Visual Studio environment to do things like enumerate projects).

If you are willing to use powershell, I would suggest the following:

**1. Make a Powershell script to handle parsing the project files out of your solution**

```
$sln = $args[0]
$projects = ((ss '= (\S+.csproj)' $sln -All) `
    | % {$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value -replace "\\\\","\"})
$configFiles = $projects -replace '(?<=\\)[^\\]+?\.csproj', 'packages.config'
'tf checkout ' + ($projects -join ' ') | iex
'tf checkout ' + ($configFiles -join ' ') | iex
('.nuget\nuget.exe update -safe -noninteractive -prerelease -source "My-Package-Repo/nuget"' `
    + $sln) | iex
```

**2. Put that powershell script in the same folder as your solution**

**3. Call that powershell script from your pre-build event**

```
powershell -file $(SolutionDir)nuget-update.ps1 "$(SolutionPath)"
```

To undo any changes to project and config files that weren't changed, run `tfpt uu noget` after the above.

Comment: This is an over complicated and unnecessary solution. Switch to Local Workspaces and you don't get read only flags on files: http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2012/11/02/local-workspaces-in-tfs-2012.aspx

Comment: @MrHinsh, thanks for that - I hadn't considered local workspaces. My team meets the caveat in that article (*"If your workspace contains more than 100,000 files, you should consider using Server workspaces instead"*), so I used the above approach myself, but local workspaces might work for others.

Comment: Local worskpaces would be great, but we are still on TFS 2010. At the moment that's not an option.  I was contemplating scripting a solution, but was hoping maybe I had just missed a commandline switch or something else.  Thanks for the PS.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a Server Workspace (a workspace configured for Server mode). You should change to a Local Workspace.

In a local workspace files are not marked as read only and can be edited outside of Visual Studio.

**Latest Nuget** - if you edit the package reference in the Nuget project file you can just remove the version number. Nuget will then always load the latest version on build.

**editing package.config** - you should exclude the /packages/ folder from source control. In the latest versions of Nuget Package Manager this is not necessary.

Comment: Even when the packages directory is excluded, the individual packages.config files that live next to the csproj files *are* checked in, and nuget.exe update needs to edit those to update version numbers of packages. Also, what version do you mean by "the latest version"? As of 2.8.5 I wasn't able to get it to define a packages.config without the `version` attributes, and so it wouldn't get the latest.

Comment: Woops... That may be a feature of Nuget 3... Ignore that line... I will delete when I get to a PC...

Comment: Oh, looks like nuget3 will be much nicer for automated builds. Thanks for pointing in that direction!

Comment: I don't want nuget to get the latest available version, I want the latest _build_ of a _specific_ version. Example, I have a dependency on AssemblyX v2.0.1 (currently under dev & publishing nightly builds). Concurently the dev team finishes AssemblyX v3.0.0 and publishes a stable package.  Following semver, v3.0.0 is not compatible with my application and I do not want to _automatically_ update to it (thus the -safe switch in my update command).  I wish [versiion range syntax](http://docs.nuget.org/create/versioning#Specifying-Version-Ranges-in-.nuspec-Files) worked on packages.config.

Comment: Me to. Did you check if Nuget 3 supports this?